# If $f'(t)=x'(t)\ \theta(T-t)$, What is the accurate formulation of $f(t)$? (antiderivative over distributions/special_functions)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, distribution-theory, piecewise-continuity

**If $f'(t)=x'(t)\ \theta(T-t)$, What is the accurate formulation of $f(t)$? (antiderivative over distributions/special_functions)**

*Maybe the question look simple, by I need to understand* **Why** *it is as so, not just to know the proper form.*

*Intro__________________________*

If I define a function as: $f(t) = x(t)\ \theta(T-t)+x(T)\ \theta(t-T)$

with $x(t)$ an arbitrary analytic function (for now, just for avoid complications with singular points), $T$ an arbitrary constant time (w.l.g., assume from now on it is such as $0<T<\infty$), and $\theta(t)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Then, by differentiation I should have:
$$\begin{array}{r c l}
f'(t) & = & x'(t)\ \theta(T-t)+x(t)\ \theta'(T-t)+\underbrace{\require{cancel}\cancel{0\ \theta(t-T)}}_{x(T)\text{ is a constant for }dt} +x(T)\ \theta'(t-T) \\
& = & x'(t)\ \theta(T-t)+\underbrace{x(t)\ \delta(T-t)\ (-1)}_{\text{but }\delta(-x)\ =\ \delta(x) \text{ and also } x(t)\delta(t-a)\ =\ x(a)\delta(t-a)} + x(T)\ \delta(t-T) \\
& = & x'(t)\ \theta(T-t)+\underbrace{-x(T)\ \delta(t-T) + x(T)\ \delta(t-T)}_{=\ 0}\\
& = & x'(t)\ \theta(T-t)
\end{array}$$
with $\delta(t)$ the [Dirac's delta function](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_de_Dirac#Propiedades).

This is why I **believe** the mentioned $f(t)$ is the proper form.

*Question________________*

But in the other way of working it out, if I have that $f'(t) = x'(t)\ \theta(T-t)$ and I apply the [indefinite integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) in both sides I will have:
$$ f(t)  =  \underbrace{\displaystyle{\int} x'(t)\ \theta(T-t)\ dt}_{\text{function of }x(t)} + \mathit{C}$$
with $\mathit{C}$ the integration constant:

- How you make appear the term $x(T)\theta(T-t)$ from the integration constant $\mathit{C}$?
- Which operations you have to make to make appear $f(t)$ from $f'(t)$ applying the [indefinite integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) operation (step-by-step)? and why "those" steps?
- Following the same logic, if I have that $g''(t)=x''(t)\ \theta(T-t)$, then what is the proper form of $g(t)$?... my guess is $g(t) = x(t)\ \theta(T-t)+\left(x(T)+x'(T)(t-T)\right)\ \theta(t-T)$, Does it means that it is required that $x'(T)\equiv 0$? (since $g(t)\neq f(t)$)

Comment: Do an integration by parts of the equation.

Comment: @md2perpe it doesn't work $$ \int x'(t)\theta(T-t)dt \\ dv=x'(t)dt\quad u=\theta(T-t) \\ \Rightarrow = x(t)\theta(T-t)-\int x(t)(-\delta(t-T))dt\\ = x(t)\theta(T-t)+\int x(t)\delta(t-T)dt$$ let me with the unknown therm $$\int x(t)\delta(t-T)dt$$: How I evaluate it?... even if I constraint it to use the sifting property $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)\delta(t-T)dt = x(T)$$ I end with a constant for all times and not the term only for $t>T$

Comment: @md2perpe if I try $\int x(t)\delta(t-a)dt$ in Wolfram-Alpha [shows nothing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+x%28t%29*diracdelta%28t-a%29*dt&lang=es), but if I use  $\int x(t)\delta(t-7)dt$ it [indeed solves](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+x%28t%29*diracdelta%28t-7%29*dt&lang=es) is equal to $x(7)\theta(t-7)+\mathit{C}$, and I don't know why?!!... hope you could elaborate in an answer, since this property isn't listed in Wikipedia website for [Dirac delta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). By the way, thanks for commenting.

Comment: @md2perpe since big part of what I am asking it is related to prove the indefinite integral over $\delta(t)$ I asked it separately in this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4664240/909869).

Comment: @md2perpe from the other question I think it follows $$\int x(t)\delta(t-T)\ dt=\int x(T)\delta(t-T)\ dt=x(T)\int\delta(t-T)dt=x(T)\theta(t-T)$$ which close the integration by parts. thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find one primitive function by integrating from an arbitrary point. Here it's natural to take the point $t=T$:
$$
f_0(t) 
= \int_T^t f'(s) \, ds
= \int_T^t x'(s) \, \theta(T-s) \, ds
\\
= \begin{cases}
x(t) - x(T), & t<T \\
0, & t>T
\end{cases}
\\
= \left( x(t)-x(T) \right) \theta(T-t).
$$

We get all solutions by adding an arbitrary constant:
$$
f(t) = f_0(t) + C = \left( x(t)-x(T) \right) \theta(T-t) + C.
$$